# SELECT multiple columns based on value of one column

Tags: mysql

I want to select specific columns based on a value of one column.

Currently, what I do is get the value of a specific column and use it to make another query. Like this:

```
SELECT service_type FROM agreements WHERE id = 1;
```

I'll pass the value to a PHP variable and make another query based on the result.

Sample code:

```
if (service == 'internet')
SELECT ipreq, latency, ... FROM agreements WHERE id = 3 AND service_type = 'internet';
else
SELECT rates, markup, ... FROM agreements WHERE id = 3 AND service_type = 'vpn';
```

Is there a way to do this without resorting to making multiple queries?

P.S.

Some of the columns comes from another table. I just want to select the specific columns from specific tables based on the value of a column (in this case, the `service_type`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, assuming that in the further course of the application you tread the result columns identically, you could try to use

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    select service, ipreq, latency, ... FROM agreements WHERE id = 3
    UNION ALL
    select service, rates, markup, ... FROM agreements WHERE id = 3
) tmp
WHERE service = 'internet'
```

This would select a combination of all possible entries for `id = 3` and then select the one you need by `service`.

However, this only works of all the fields have identical types.

Probably you should also rename the fields to unify access to them, like

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    select service, ipreq as field1, latency as field2, ... FROM agreements WHERE id = 3
    UNION ALL
    select service, rates as field1, markup as field2, ... FROM agreements WHERE id = 3
) tmp
WHERE service = 'internet'
```

If you don't want to do that, you need to access them by column index in your application. Still the field types need to be the same.

**EDIT:**

Here is the updated code:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
     SELECT doc.id as docid, service, ipreq, latency,... FROM agreements WHERE service = 1
     UNION ALL
     SELECT doc.id as docid, service, rates, markup,... FROM agreements WHERE service = 2
) as tmp
WHERE docid = 1
```

Now this code will select all fields pertaining to the specific service type.

Comment: This will mean that I will still have to get the value of `service` beforehand, right?

Comment: Well, that depends. Using the above approach you could also get all possible entries for `id = 3` by removing the outer `SELECT`. You could then filter within your application. In your sample code, however, you selected the service type already, adjusting the query according to it, so I thought that was given.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying Thorsten. I am currently trying this and see if it will work the way I want it to be.

Comment: This works for me, though I ended up altering it a bit. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Mysql supports the [Control Flow Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) which allows you to build your IF/ELSE right inside the query. You can even use [Subqueries](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subqueries.html) inside of the If/Else statements, to create very dynamic select statements.